# get raw touch data from Wacom touchpad

Tags: touch, multi-touch, touchpad, wacom

I have a [Wacom Bamboo](http://www.wacom.com/en/Products/Bamboo/BambooTablets.aspx) multitouch-pad and want to use it as an input device. It is connected to my pc. How can I get the raw touch data? For instance, if I'm touching at position {x,y} on touchpad, my application should get this point and send this point as message. Please someone guide me or give me some clues. I didn't find any threads about that.

Comment: 5 seconds of googling http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/docs/WacomWindevFAQ.html#_Toc276983612

Comment: @Zipper I believe the multitouch reference there applies only to wacom tablet/touchscreen PCs, not something like the Bamboo.

Comment: Here is a list of wacom tablets which can provide raw touch point data:
http://www.wacomeng.com/touch/WacomFeelMulti-TouchFAQ.htm#_Toc331140757